# Why my element undefined in code but defined if I run the code in console js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, console, pageload

I'm trying to add a button to an element on YouTube with the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let elm = document.getElementsByClassName("style-scope ytd-guide-section-renderer")[8];
  let nbutton = document.createElement("button");
  elm.append(nbutton);
}, false);
```

Unfortunately, I'm always getting the error:

> *cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'append')*

When I run the code in console, after the page is loaded, everything works fine.

I thought, the problem is, that the page isn't fully loaded before I'm trying to access the element, so I added a page load event listener, but It's still not working.

No other question helped me, I think it's a specific issue of the YouTube page, so please don't mark my question as duplicate

Comment: If the element isn't found then it doesn't exist at that time.  What elements are found by that call to `getElementsByClassName`?  How do they differ from what's expected?  Is anything dynamically changing the DOM after the page is initially loaded?

Comment: use `appendChild` for javascript and `append` for jQuery library

Comment: Most likely the element is added to the DOM after the page had loaded. You can use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to determine when the element is added to the page.